# Replicating test sheet from React+Bootstrap Template throwing syntax error

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

I am new to ReactJS and Bootstrap, so please forgive me if this question is ignorant.

I am adding a page to an existing template, and I can get it to show up in the side navbar, and it opens when I click on it.

I went to add content to the new page, and just copied some files over from an existing page in the template to test it out, and it has thrown this error. I don't know why it would work on one page and then not another, and I don't think following the advice to edit the syntax is going to fix anything.

```
*SyntaxError: d:\hyper-react-v3.0\hyper\src\components\Datepicker.js: Missing semicolon (6:4)

4 | import classNames from 'classnames';
5 |
6 | type DatepickerInputProps = {
  |     ^
7 |     onClick?: () => void,
8 |     value?: string,
9 | };
```